# Loading an app conditionally with and without spinner

Tags: html, css, angular

In my angular app. I have two different layouts. one for my Login page and the other for remaining pages. I have a spinner in my index.html implemented during loading of the app. How can i conditionally disable and enable the spinner based on the the component loading.
I want to implement the style of the spinner in inner.html only if the condtion user.logged is true in app.component.html. How can i implement it. please guide me.

app.compoonent.html

`````
<nb-layout>
      <nb-layout-column>
        <nb-card>
<ngx-login></ngx-login>
        </nb-card>
      </nb-layout-column>
    </nb-layout>


    <ngx-one-column-layout *ngIf="user.logged">
      <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ngx-one-column-layout>````
`````

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Myapp</title>

  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCpVhQiwAllg1RAFaxMWSpQruuGARy0Y1k&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--  <ngx-app>Loading...</ngx-app>-->
  <ngx-app></ngx-app>

  <style>@-webkit-keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}@-moz-keyframes spin{0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0)}100%{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}.spinner{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1003;background: #000000;overflow:hidden}  .spinner div:first-child{display:block;position:relative;left:50%;top:50%;width:150px;height:150px;margin:-75px 0 0 -75px;border-radius:50%;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(255,56,106,1);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);animation:spin 2s linear infinite}  .spinner div:first-child:after,.spinner div:first-child:before{content:'';position:absolute;border-radius:50%}  .spinner div:first-child:before{top:5px;left:5px;right:5px;bottom:5px;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgb(255, 228, 32);-webkit-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;animation:spin 3s linear infinite}  .spinner div:first-child:after{top:15px;left:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(61, 175, 255,1);animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite}</style>
  <div id="nb-global-spinner" class="spinner">
    <div class="blob blob-0"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-1"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-2"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-3"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-4"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-5"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the loader code within the `<ngx-app>` like this:

```html
  <ngx-app>
  <style>@-webkit-keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}@-moz-keyframes spin{0%{-moz-transform:rotate(0)}100%{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes spin{0%{transform:rotate(0)}100%{transform:rotate(360deg)}}.spinner{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1003;background: #000000;overflow:hidden}  .spinner div:first-child{display:block;position:relative;left:50%;top:50%;width:150px;height:150px;margin:-75px 0 0 -75px;border-radius:50%;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(255,56,106,1);transform:translate3d(0,0,0);animation:spin 2s linear infinite}  .spinner div:first-child:after,.spinner div:first-child:before{content:'';position:absolute;border-radius:50%}  .spinner div:first-child:before{top:5px;left:5px;right:5px;bottom:5px;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgb(255, 228, 32);-webkit-animation:spin 3s linear infinite;animation:spin 3s linear infinite}  .spinner div:first-child:after{top:15px;left:15px;right:15px;bottom:15px;box-shadow:0 3px 3px 0 rgba(61, 175, 255,1);animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite}</style>
  <div id="nb-global-spinner" class="spinner">
    <div class="blob blob-0"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-1"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-2"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-3"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-4"></div>
    <div class="blob blob-5"></div>
  </div>
  </ngx-app>
```